# Retrieve a cell text based on a number from different column in excel/google sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

So, I have some sort of a score table:
 In column A are listed the names of contestants and through column B to I there are the partial scores; and column J has the total score. 
 Then, in a random cell in column L I've used `MAX`function to retrieve the highest score from my table; but, where I am stuck is that I am trying to figure out a way where, using a function, the cell next to L automatically returns the name of the contestant with the highest score (the score in cell L). 
I have tried with `VLOOKUP` function, but I can't get it right, because column A is text and not a value.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index and match. Put this in column L:

```
=index(A2:A,match(max(J2:J),J2:J,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ed Nelson! That worked perfectly!

Comment: If this works for you, could you please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.